# Windows reverse engineered?

Tags: windows

Have read in some Discord channel, that Windows was reverse engineered. Does anybody here have knowledge about such reverse engineered Windows version? If it really exists, where can it be downloaded?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133047/discussion-on-question-by-convert-windows-reverse-engineered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the answer to my question in the comment moved to chat, I am going to write it here again. The OS which meets my requirements the best is [React OS](https://reactos.org/).